# How to print a string in an object in PHP

Tags: php, date, object

I get the following object in response to a call in PHP:

> Transaction[id=g855fm, type=sale, amount=100.00,
>        status=processed, createdAt=Tuesday, 24-Jun-14 19:17:58
>        UTC]

I am able to echo `id`, `amount`, `status` etc. but `createdAt` does not print. Perhaps because it has a comma (,) in it? I want to convert the sate from string format to mm/dd/yyyy but I can not format it to mm/dd/yyyy because I am not able to get createdAt.

`echo $object->createdAt;` prints nothing.

`echo $object->id;` prints `g855fm`.

`echo $object->status;` prints `processed`.

This is the whole object:

```
Braintree_Subscription[
    addOns=,
    balance=0.00,
    billingDayOfMonth=24,
    billingPeriodEndDate=Wednesday, 23-Jul-14 00:00:00 MDT,
    billingPeriodStartDate=Tuesday, 24-Jun-14 00:00:00 MDT,
    currentBillingCycle=1,
    daysPastDue=,
    discounts=,
    failureCount=0,
    firstBillingDate=Tuesday, 24-Jun-14 00:00:00 MDT,
    id=6q6qg2,
    merchantAccountId=XXXX,
    neverExpires=1,
    nextBillAmount=100.00,
    nextBillingPeriodAmount=100.00,
    nextBillingDate=Thursday, 24-Jul-14 00:00:00 MDT,
    numberOfBillingCycles=,
    paidThroughDate=Wednesday, 23-Jul-14 00:00:00 MDT,
    paymentMethodToken=3mzhf6,
    planId=XXXX,
    price=100.00,
    status=Active,
    trialDuration=,
    trialDurationUnit=day,
    trialPeriod=,
    descriptor=Braintree_Descriptor[
        name=, phone=
        ],
    transactions=
    0=Braintree_Transaction[
        id=h2v7qm,
        type=sale,
        amount=100.00,
        status=submitted_for_settlement,
        createdAt=Wednesday, 25-Jun-14 03:53:07 UTC,
        creditCardDetails=Braintree_Transaction_CreditCardDetails[
            token=3mzhf6,
            bin=411111,
            last4=1111,
            cardType=Visa,
            expirationMonth=06,
            expirationYear=2014,
            customerLocation=US,
            cardholderName=,
            imageUrl=https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox&merchant_id=XXXX,
            prepaid=Unknown,
            healthcare=Unknown,
            debit=Unknown,
            durbinRegulated=Unknown,
            commercial=Unknown,
            payroll=Unknown,
            issuingBank=Unknown,
            countryOfIssuance=Unknown,
            productId=Unknown,
            venmoSdk=,
            expirationDate=06/2014,
            maskedNumber=411111******1111
        ],
        customerDetails=Braintree_Transaction_CustomerDetails[
            id=59273593,
            firstName=XXXX,
            lastName=,
            company=,
            email=XXXX,
            website=,
            phone=XXXX,
            fax=
        ]
    ]
]
```

I am accessing it like: `$object->transactions[0]->createdAt`

Update:

`echo $object->transactions[0]->createdAt->format('r');` is: Wed, 25 Jun 2014 04:07:42 +0000

I will now try to use it now for date formatting. I want it in `date(dd/mm/yyyy)` format. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: `echo $object->createdAt`?

Comment: Did that. echo $object->createdAt; prints nothing.

Comment: maybe `createdAt` is private to object, check the scope of `createdAt`.

Comment: what's the exact 'php call' and how are you displaying the string you are showing us?

Comment: var dump of the object may be helpful here!

Comment: $webhookNotification->subscription->transactions[0] prints everything, var_dump($webhookNotification->subscription->transactions[0]) prints nothing

Comment: i find that unbelievably odd.

Comment: I have now pasted whole object in the question.

Comment: How do I check if createdAt is private?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $object->transactions[0]->createdAt->format('r');`?

Comment: $object->transactions[0]->createdAt->format('r'); is: Wed, 25 Jun 2014 04:07:42 +0000

Comment: I will now try to use it now for date formatting. I want it in date(dd/mm/yyyy) format. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have turned off display errors. When trying to echo DateTime object you are receiving silent fatal error.

Try `echo $object->transactions[0]->createdAt->format('d/m/Y');`

Comment: Only Derick would think of throwing an exception when a `(string)` cast is attempted =p

Answer (score 1):

You should call print the object like this

```
<?php print_r($object); ?>
```